# Pandas dataframe marking batch of rows following change in column data pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following (sample) dataframe df:

```
data_list = [
    1521811600,
    1521811600,
    1521811600,
    1521811601,
    315964847,
    315964841,
    315964841,
    315964841,
    315964841,
    315964841,
    315964841,
    315964841,
    1521811601,
    1521811601,
    1521811601,
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':data_list, 'flag':[0]*len(data_list)})
```

Thus:

```
          data   flag
0   1521811600      0
1   1521811600      0
2   1521811600      0
3   1521811601      0
4    315964847      0
5    315964841      0
6    315964841      0
7    315964841      0
8    315964841      0
9    315964841      0
10   315964841      0
11   315964841      0
12  1521811601      0
13  1521811601      0
14  1521811601      0
```

The 'data' column is supposed to be a series of ascending timestamps with no jumps in time.  Sometimes in the acquisition process I get some data that is clearly invalid (some sort of rollback or jumpahead).  I'd like to identify and tag this data with some special marker values in the flag column.

I'd like to mark all the rows that have ascending and contiguous data (differing only by 0 or 1) with a "flag" result of 1.  I want to mark the FIRST occurrence of bogus data (either a jump backward, or a jump forward greater than 1) with a "flag" result of 2.  I need to tag the SECOND occurrence of bad data, thru the end of the bad data, with a "flag" result of 3.

Ideally this is what I would end up with for the dataframe above:

```
          data   flag
0   1521811600      1
1   1521811600      1
2   1521811600      1
3   1521811601      1
4    315964847      2
5    315964841      3
6    315964841      3
7    315964841      3
8    315964841      3
9    315964841      3
10   315964841      3
11   315964841      3
12  1521811601      1
13  1521811601      1
14  1521811601      1
```

Other than what is stated above I can't make any assumptions about the data.  For example, the fact that the first bogus data value (*847) is different than the others (*841) is of no relevance; neither is the bogus data values starting right after the good data values "tick" up from *600 to *601.

Maybe worth pointing out is that there may be only ONE bogus data value, in which case there would be no records flagged with 3, example desired output (this time showing a jump forward in time instead of back):

```
          data   flag
0   1521811599      1
1   1521811599      1
2   1521811599      1
3   2423603027      2
4   1521811599      1
5   1521811599      1
6   1521811599      1
```

I'm at a loss as to how to do this in a "pandonic"/"pandastic"/"pandemic"?! way...searching for the one word term to use for Pandas like when people say for normal Python: "I don't know how to do something in a Pythonic way"...

I did come up with some truly horrid code to do this more "manually" manipulating indexes, but I never got it totally correct and it was a total mess.  It seems like, with Pandas, trying to do something without the Pandonic approach gets ugly fast, but at least that serves as a really obvious clue that you are doing it WRONGLY.

Comment: `df.data.sort_values().diff().isin([0,1]).ne(True).cumsum().sort_index()
`

Comment: @Wen Interesting, thanks.  Doesn't quite meet the spec (sometimes the flagging values are changed around, 3 is marked as 1 and vice versa).  I've made the decision that this is "too much" for a simple Pandas solution and I've gone with non-Pandas procedural code correcting this situation in the data file before pulling it into a dataframe.  I definitely picked up some previously-unknown-to-me techniques though.